# in Embedded C, how to convert a Returned Hex value in the form of "Unsigned Char" to usable "Integer" type

Tags: c, integer, char, hex

We are writing a code for I2C interface, 
where we are reading a 16 bit Hex number as two 8 bit Hex MSB and LSB, and we are returning these values as  "Unsigned Char".

we want to concatenate these MSB and LSB **"char"** values, and finally we need one **"Integer"** value for our further processing.

for example: the following 2 methods are returning one **"Unsigned Char"** value, each

1)

```
unsigned char i2c_readAck(void)
{
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEN) | (1<<TWEA);
    while(!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));

    return TWDR;

}/* i2c_readAck */
```

2)

```
unsigned char i2c_readNak(void)
{
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEN);
    while(!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));

    return TWDR;

}/* i2c_readNak */
```

we have to fetch MSB and LSB values from these 2 methods who are actual HEX values needed, 
but in unsigned char type, concatenate it,  and the finally the concatenated value must be converted to usable Integer format,

we are finding the the conversation part very tricky, 
can anyone help us??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need something like this:

```
unsigned char msb = ...; // read MSB
unsigned char lsb = ...; // read LSB
int val = (msb << 8) | lsb; // combine MSB and LSB to make an int
```

Comment: paul, we are just very new to this embedded c, so asking this question again, please dont mind, as seen the msb and lsb values are of data type "char" , Can we do bitwise operations on it directly?? and then can we directly store it on "int" without type casting..wont it be a type casting issue ??

Comment: and thank you paul, for answering it instantly...!..please answer my above quarry too,

Comment: @Balaji KR: a char is just a small int and it will be implicitly promoted to int in the above expression - I suggest you just try the above code and see if it works for you.

Comment: @ paul...thank you soo much..i was working on java before...and i am subjected to too much JAVA theory overdose which is making me asking such silly questions in C...lol...thank you soo much for answering...your answer holds good!

Comment: You should actually use `unsigned char` rather than `char` to hold `msb` and `lsb`, because `char` may be signed.  The shift and bitwise-or will give completely the wrong result for negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is tricky and hard to visualize. Remember that the MSB and LSB you get (probably) are the actual binary representations you need; you don't need to convert those things. That's how i2c works. So:

```
  int number = 0, msb, lsb;

  msb = 0xff & read_one_unsigned_i2c_byte();
  lsb = 0xff & read_one_unsigned_i2c_byte();

  number = msb << 8;      // gotta' shift msb to upper 8 bits of final result
  number = number | lsb;  // and then IOR in the lower 8 bits
```

-- pete

Comment: thank you soo much pete, actually i started working on java, and i feel afraid to move forward in each step writing a code as i visualize a TYPE CASTING error in it..! as i say its just visualization and i step back to write that code..lol.

Comment: Yes, LOL, but not to worry. When you try one of the two solutions given above, you'll see it works like a champ.